# Example of an axiomatic system

Tags: logic

Build an axiomatic system that is effective, complete  but not valid.

I thought as the only deduction rule $\psi \rightarrow \neg \psi $ and only axiom **n** $\approx$ **n** where theorem is $\neg[$ **n** $\approx$ **n**] but this is not true. Is this correct or how I can make the construction. Thanks

Comment: I think that we have to improve the terminolgy. What are you meaning with "valid" ? I suppose you are asking for a system that is not *sound*, i.e.that proves false sentences. Or are you asking for *unsound* rules (i.e.rules that derive false conclusion from true premises) ?

Answer (score 3):

If we assume a language with the $\lnot$ connective, we can use your proposed rule :

> from $\psi$, infer $\lnot \psi$

to derive $\lnot (n ≈ n )$ from the axiom.

In this case the system is **not** *sound*, because we can prove a *false* theorem.

But from a theorem $\varphi$ wathever, applying the rule again, we can derive : $\lnot \varphi$, i.e. its negation.

Thus, the system is *complete* in a trivial way.

Comment: By "not sound" you mean "not sound for two-valued semantics" correct?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood - yes; as you can see from this and the previous post, we have very few info by the OP about the "initial conditions" of the problems : language, semantics, ... Thus I assumed the "standard" case.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation).

Suppose our only rule of inferences are detachment from {$\vdash$C$\alpha$$\beta$, $\vdash$$\alpha$} we may infer $\beta$, and uniform substitution.

Suppose our only only axiom is Cpq.

Now what can we do with Cpq?  Well, let's say we substitute p with a and q with b obtaining Cab.  Thus, we have Cpq and Cab as theorems.  Can we place either of these theorems into the antecedent of the other theorem?  Sure, suppose we substitute p with Cab.  Then we have CCabq as a theorem.  Then since we have CCabq, and Cab as theorems, we can detach q as a theorem.  But then we can substitute q by "falsum" or "0".  Consequently, if we have two truth values this system is unsound (but if we only had one truth value it turns out that our system would qualify as sound, and Cpq could serve as the sole axiom for "one-valued" logic).